# Dismiss keyboard in multiline TextInput in React native

Tags: react-native

When the user presses the `Return` key in a multiline `TextInput`, a new line is created and the keyboard continues to be visible. How should the keyboard be dismissed for multiline TextInput in React native?

I did some research. I found that clicking on the `View` outside the `TextInput` does not blur the TextInput, which is causing the keyboard to remain visible.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <TextInput
    placeholder="To"
    style={styles.input}
    value={this.state.to}
    onChangeText={(to) => this.setState({to})}
  />
  <TextInput
    placeholder="Text"
    style={styles.textarea}
    multiline={true}
    numberOfLines={4}
    value={this.state.text}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
  />
</View>
```

For `ScrollView`, there is a prop - `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` which causes the `TextInput` to blur. Is there any equivalent of that for `View`? I want the multiline TextInput to blur so that the keyboard gets dismissed.

Comment: `returnKeyType={'done'}`. See:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#returnkeytype

Comment: Done creates a new line. It only changes the text, not the behavior of the return key.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`TextInput` has a `blurOnSubmit` prop; when set to true, the return key dismisses the keyboard.

However currently the prop does not work on Android. I've posted an issue on the subject:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8778

Comment: For Multiline TextInput, return key enters a new line and not dismiss the keyboard. So, clicking on some other part of the View should dismiss the keyboard.

Comment: @Vijay From React Native docs:
"Note that for multiline fields, setting blurOnSubmit to true means that pressing return will blur the field and trigger the onSubmitEditing event instead of inserting a newline into the field."

Comment: Is there another way to enter new line? If not, I prefer return to enter new line, and clicking on another part of View to dismiss the keyboard.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I couldn't find any easy way to dismiss the keyboard with a View, a workaround would be to use `ScrollView` and set `scrollEnabled` prop to false.

Comment: This appears to be fixed in 0.46.4.

Comment: But I want to be able to enter a new line and also dismiss the keyboard with a button. This is basic functionality

Answer (score 25):

**Hope it helps other , as wasted time on reading many github threads and issues..**

By doing below code , you **keyboard** show return key you wanted for **example** `"done", "go"`  and also **dismiss** the keyboard when you **press** return key in my case `done` key while using **multi line** seamlessly.

```
import {Textinput, ScrollView, Keyboard} from 'react-native';

// ...code 

 <TextInput
     keyboardType="default"
     returnKeyType="done"
     multiline={true}
     blurOnSubmit={true}
     onSubmitEditing={()=>{Keyboard.dismiss()}}
  />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, looks like this adds an extra newline each time they tap the done button.

Comment: It seems you also need to declare `numberOfLines` for this to work

Comment: @DrorBar not sure, its been more then 5 years. there must have lots of changes in react native library in between. it used to work without extra argument, when i answered this question

Answer (score 8):

This is a simplified version of austin's very helpful answer above.

If you convert the `View` you have for your screen/component into a `TouchableOpacity` with `activeOpacity={1}` (this prevents any fading or opacity effects), you can then pass it:

```
onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}
```

Make sure you've imported TouchableOpacity and Keyboard from 'react-native' and you're good.

Comment: @FortuneCookie. This Answer is from dan674. I only edited  his answer to add code formatting. As this was his post, he'll automatically be notified of all comments left to this post. Perhaps he'll be able to help?

Answer (score 4):

Banged my head against this for a few hours and after fiddling around and some dumb luck finally figured out how to make a multiline TextInput dismiss by just touching outside the text box. Little Example for ya'll hope that someone else finds this useful because the docs do not make it all apparent that you can get multilines to dismiss easily...

```
import React, { Component}  from 'react'`
import {
keyboardAvoidingView,
Keyboard,
StatusBar,
StyleSheet,
TextInput,
View,
} from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {
constructor(props){
super(props)
this.state ={
        behavior: 'position',
}
this._keyboardDismiss =  this._keyboardDismiss.bind(this);
}
componentWillMount() {
this.keyboardDidHideListener = 
                  Keyboard
                 .addListener('keyboardDidHide',this._keyboardDidHide);                                                         
              }

componentWillUnmount(){
this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
}

_keyboardDidHide() {
Keyboard.dismiss();
}

render() {

return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView 
      style{{flex:1}}
      behavior={this.state.behavior}
    >
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={this._keyboardDidHide}
    >
    <View>
      <TextInput
          style={ 
          color: '#000',
          paddingLeft: 15,
          paddingTop: 10,
          fontSize: 18,t}
          multiline={true}
          textStyle={{ fontSize: '20', fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Medium' }}
          placeholder="Share your Success..."
          value={this.state.text}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          returnKeyType={'default'}
       />
    </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>

    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To complete my comment about `returnKeyType`, you also need to set `blurOnSubmit={true}` which will trigger `onSubmitEditing` event handler too when Done is pressed.

See example https://rnplay.org/apps/0HIrmw for details.

Comment: I want the keyboard to be dismissed when clicking on some other part of the View, not on clicking Done.

Answer (score 2):

as long as there is only one done button, we still need to decide what this return/done button does. In this case I will propose adding another dismiss button to the keyboard by using InputAccessoryView. Following code is copied from https://dev.to/vladimirvovk/react-native-ios-keyboard-with-a-custom-button-15h0

```
<TextInput
      ...
      inputAccessoryViewID="Next"
    />
    <TextInput
      ...
      ref={nextFieldRef}
      inputAccessoryViewID="Done"
    />
    
    <InputAccessoryView nativeID="Next">
      <View style={styles.accessory}>
        <Button
          onPress={() => nextFieldRef.current.focus()}
          title="Next"
        />
      </View>
    </InputAccessoryView>
```

Comment: Best one (Y) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still having trouble with this, specifically around keeping the return key for adding new lines and dismissing the keyboard when clicking outside of the input, the regular view component does not blur the TextField when you click outside of the component. However if you use a ScrollView instead of a regular View it will trigger the onBlur effect when you click anywhere on the screen and the below code will dismiss the keyboard and keep the return key for adding new lines. You can set `scrollEnabled={false}` on the scroll view if you don't want scrolling and it will still trigger the events

```js
<TextField
  value={value}
  placeholder="Description..."
  multiline
  numberOfLines={20}
  keyboardType="default"
  onBlur={() => {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Keyboard.dismiss() solved the issue for me.

```
 <TextInput
 keyboardType="default"
 returnKeyType="done"
 multiline={true}
 blurOnSubmit={true}
 onSubmitEditing={()=>{Keyboard.dismiss()}}
```

/>