# can't tap on button without closing the keyboard

Tags: javascript, react-native, buttonclick

I am using `react native 0.4`

I have a [modal](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html) with a TextInput, if i want to tap on one of the buttons that are on the modal I need to tap it twice - first tap closes the keyboard and only then I can tap on the button.
I would like to be able to tap on buttons that are on the modal without closing the keyborad.

[image]

Comment: Hi @yossi, did you see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38981117/dismiss-keyboard-in-multiline-textinput-in-react-native/41931179#41931179). It may help you.

Comment: Hi @yossi, I'm experiencing the same issue...did you find a solution for that?

Comment: I am having the same issue , did u find the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem on my flatlist, but i found keyboardShouldPersistTaps = true fixed it, maybe modal uses a list behind the scenes and you can just add keyboardShouldPersistTaps?