# multiline text input with newline and keyboard dismiss key buttons

Tags: react-native

So I've been struggling with this on iOS: I want a multiline text input that allows adding a new line:

```
// Now there's a "return" button, that adds a new line, perfect!

<TextInput
  multiline
  numberOfLines={2}
/>
```

And at the same time I want a multiline text input with a return key, that dismisses the keyboard (so the user can continue scrolling down the screen to the submit CTA):

```
// Now there's a "done" button, that dismisses the keyboard, yay!

<TextInput
  blurOnSubmit
  multiline
  numberOfLines={2}
  returnKeyType="done"
/>
```

However, I can't find a way how to combine these two. With other keyboard types (such as *number*) there is *returnKey* above the keyboard itself.

Is there a way to have multiline text input with both - new line button and keyboard dismiss key? Thanks!

Edit:

[Expo snack: https://snack.expo.io/@mattz/77a2d1](https://snack.expo.io/@mattz/77a2d1)

Comment: can you please share an expo snack with a working oslution so that i can check there

Comment: hey Gaurav! I added the snack to the description

Comment: @matt93 I've been looking for the same functionality (surely it's not uncommon developers would want a multi-line text field that supports new line characters but can also dismiss the keyboard easily). So far my best find is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49040242/1609914 Hope this helps! It doesn't provide the second button, but it does allow dismissing the keyboard on the containing element being tapped

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still looking for the answer, I'm posting it here

You could add a wrapper `(TouchableOpacity or Pressable)` similar to the solution given by `James`, for the `TextInput` and dismiss the keyboard with an outside click.

```
import { TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Keyboard } from 'react-native';

<TouchableOpacity onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
  <View>
     <TextInput
      blurOnSubmit
      multiline
      numberOfLines={2}
      returnKeyType="done"
      ....
    />
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `InputAccessoryView` with a "Done" `Pressable` that runs `Keyboard.dismiss` in it's `onPress` handler.